# How can I put many objects in a Map with the same parameter name

Tags: java

I have this code but it seems to over write one parameter and I only end up with one `myImages` parameter no matter how many values i have in `imagesList`

Is there a way to put the put many objects in a Map with the same name?

```
for(String imagePath: imagesList){
        File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
        params.put("myImages", imageFile);
    }
```

**edit**
I must use a map since a library that i am using to make multipart POST requests requires that i put the file in a map

Comment: You can't do this in a `Map`. It would be better if you put a `List` as value instead of each single object.

Comment: That's not how a map works - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You could use a `Map<String, Collection<File>>` or a guava `Multimap`.

Comment: If you really need this functionality, may be consider something like multimap (from Guava)

Comment: You can put them in an List in the Map, or give the key a suffix -- "myImages.1", myImages.2", etc.  Or don't use a Map.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a collection as the `Map` value.

A `Map` stores a unique key -> value mapping so putting the same value again simply overwrites it. You can either use a `Map<String, Collection<File>>` like so:

```
final Map<String, Collection<File>> myMap = new HashMap<String, Collection<File>>();
//...
Collection<File> files = myMap.get("myImages");
if(files == null) {
    files = new LinkedList<File>();
    myMap.put("myImages", files);
}
for(String imagePath: imagesList){
    File imageFile = new File(imagePath);        
    files.add(imageFile);
}
```

Or you could consider using a `Multimap` implementation from the likes of [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained).

Comment: Exactly What I would have also answered :) +1.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned use Guava's [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html), it allows you to associate many values against a single key, for example:

```
Multimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
multimap.put("myImages", file1);
multimap.put("myImages", file2);
multimap.put("myImages", file3);

Collection<File> images = multimap.get("myImages");
```